# Из восьмеричной системы счисления в десятеричную

Tags: c++, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Как перевести из восьмеричной системы счисления в десятеричную?

Написал такую функцию:

```
void OctToDec(int n, ...)
{
    int number = 1; //учитывается и переданный индикатор конца списка фактических параметров
    int *ptr_ = &n; 

    while (*ptr_) //цикл, пока не встретится нулевой элемент списка
    {
        number++; //наращивание счетчика параметров
        ptr_++; //продвижение указателя на следующее слово стека
    }       
    cout << "Функции Example передано " << number-1 << " параметра(-ов)\n";
    int *ptr = &n;
    while (*ptr) 
    {
        bool flag = false;
        string temp = to_string(*ptr);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
        {
            if ((temp[i] >= '0') || (temp[i] <= '7'))
                flag = true;
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true)
        {
            int r = 0, f = 1;

            for (int i = temp.length(); i>0; --i)
            {
            r = r + f*((char)(temp[i]) - 48);
            f = f * 8;
            }
            if (number == 4)
                cout << *ptr << " -> " << r << endl;
            else if (number == 7)
                cout << *ptr << " -> " << r << endl;
            else if (number == 8)
                cout << *ptr << " -> " << r << endl;
        }
        ptr++; 
    }
}
```

В нее передаю параметры так

```
OctToDec(772, 467, 777, 0);
OctToDec(536, 225, 112, 35, 557, 645, 0);
OctToDec(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 0);
```

Код нашел на Pascal-e тут http://www.cyberforum.ru/turbo-pascal/thread723834.html

Comment: Что значит "СС"?

Comment: Система счисления

Comment: Функция `void OctToDec(int n, ...)` ожидает кол-во чисел и сами числа. Вы же передаете количество = 772, 536, 100 + никак не используете переданные параметры. Как использовать вариативное число параметров описано тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c

Comment: Нет, в *ptr как раз таки попадают значения,  и я их пытался использовать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант

```
int octToDec(int num)
{
    int res = 0, k = log10(num), i = 0;
    char numBuff[100];
    _itoa_s(num, numBuff, 8);

    while (i <= k)
    {
        res += (numBuff[i] - '0')*std::pow(8, k - i); ++i;
    }

    return res;
}

int x = 033456; //  3*8^4 + 3*8^3 + 4*8^2 + 5*8^1 + 6*8^0 = 14126 

cout << octToDec(x); // 14126
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал так:

```
void OctToDec(int n, ...)
{
    int number = 1; //учитывается и переданный индикатор конца списка фактических параметров
    int *ptr_ = &n; 

    while (*ptr_) //цикл, пока не встретится нулевой элемент списка
    {
        number++; //наращивание счетчика параметров
        ptr_++; //продвижение указателя на следующее слово стека
    }       
    cout << "Функции Example передано " << number-1 << " параметра(-ов) и 0" << endl;
    int *ptr = &n;
    while (*ptr) 
    {
        bool flag = false;
        string temp = to_string(*ptr);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
        {
            if ((temp[i] >= '0') || (temp[i] <= '7'))
                flag = true;
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }   
        if (flag == true)
        {
            int s, k, p;
            s = 0;
            p = temp.length() - 1;
            for (int i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                switch (temp[i])
                {
                case '1': k = 1; break;
                case '2': k = 2; break;
                case '3': k = 3; break;
                case '4': k = 4; break;
                case '5': k = 5; break;
                case '6': k = 6; break;
                case '7': k = 7; break;
                case '0': k = 0; break;
                }
                s = s + k*pow(8, p);
                p--;
            }
            cout << *ptr << " -> " << s << endl;
        }
        ptr++; 
    }
}
```

Вызываю все так же

```
OctToDec(772, 467, 777, 0);
OctToDec(536, 225, 112, 35, 557, 645, 0);
OctToDec(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 0);
```

Работает=)

Comment: Зачем писать ```...```, если va_args никто не использует? (хотя надо бы, я писал про это выше). Что мешает в таком случае (последним останется ноль, эдакий нуль-терминированный массив) передавать int* n? Если я правильно помню, то стандарт не гарантирует, что аргументы функции будут расположены рядом (call convention), и Вам сейчас везёт, что это работает. Хотите передавать переменное число аргументов - передавайте `std::vector<int>` значений. Я считаю, в данном случае это самое правильное решение